# Wordpress Action "update_user_meta"

Tags: wordpress, metadata, action

Im trying to create an action when a user meta value is updated, another meta value of the same user will be updated. Like this:

```
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields');

function update_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'meta_to_store', $_POST['my_meta_stored_field']);

}
```

I can not understand the procedure, any ideas? Thanks in advance;

NOTE: Now works! Thanks Amin.T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not the right hook and you are missing some functions parameters, so you need something like this:

```
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields');

 function update_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {
      $new_value = "new_value";
      update_user_meta($user_id, 'other_meta', $new_value);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Amin! It works but there has been me another problem. 

If "$ new_value" is a target of the same user using "$ user_id" does not work.

$new_value = get_user_meta($user_id, 'meta_stored', true);

However if I add the userid it works perfectly.

$new_value = get_user_meta(4, 'meta_stored', true);

How you should call the user ide?